# How do I set the Select Date from a dropdown text field after date pick in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set the Select Date from a Dropdown dialog in Jetpack Compose. But the selected date does not appear on the "Select Date" placeholder. How do I do that?

```
package com.example.bettehomes.components.composable

import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowDropDown
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import java.time.LocalDate

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Composable
fun DateDropdownTextField(selectedDate: LocalDate?, onDateSelected: (LocalDate?) -> Unit) {
    val showDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val placeholderText = remember(selectedDate) {
        selectedDate?.toString() ?: "Select Date"
    }

    if (showDialog.value) {
        MyCalendarDialog { newDate ->
            onDateSelected(newDate as LocalDate?)
            showDialog.value = false
        }
    }

    TextField(
        value = selectedDate?.toString() ?: "",
        onValueChange = { /* do nothing to make it read-only */ },
        label = { Text("Select Date") },
        trailingIcon = {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { showDialog.value = true },
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = "Open calendar")
            }
        },
        readOnly = true,
        placeholder = { Text("Select Date") }
    )
}
```